# Windows Phone 8.1 Battery Drainage

Tags: battery, 8.1

I get the feeling that after updating my WP to 8.1, the battery drains faster. Does anyone else get the same issue? is there a solution for this?

Comment: I have the same feeling. I'm still think it's because I'm playing it a lot.

Comment: Do you use Cortana? She requires GPS to be enabled, which might contribute to higher power usage.

Comment: I don't use Cortana too much and I have checked the Battery app. It showed some app to be using background and I have disabled it for these app, but still battery is going down fast. Tried turning off NFC, WIFI Sense and some others and still the same.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.... disabled all background tasks.... no result.... please provide any sol for this prob.....

Comment: @prasenjeet How long has it been since you upgraded to 8.1? Have you checked app power usage in Battery Sense? Do you have wireless radios like GPS, NFC etc. always on?

Comment: It will be usefull if u share your experience with developers..

Comment: It was fixed by Microsoft update to WP8.1

Answer (score 5):

The new battery saver app introduced in 8.1 should show you battery use by app since you last rebooted the phone. On a phone that has *just* been turned on, it points a finger of blame at HERE Maps and People; obviously your battery usage will be different, and activities like chatting Cortana up will use a fair amount (after all, speech recognition isn't trivial, from a processing perspective), but this new app should let you identify if it's using a specific app that's causing the issue, if it's background tasks.

Of course, if you're actually using your phone more, I'd expect the battery to be used more :)

Comment: Not playing with it more than I have "played" with WP8. Battery is going down faster. Tried turning Cortana off and still...

Comment: @Etchin Did you try disable location?

Answer (score 4):

High battery drain after updating to WP 8.1 is not an isolated problem its all over the forums.

I'm pretty sure this is the problem with geofencing.

*Geofencing* is a new feature in Windows Phone 8.1. The phone keeps on checking your location continuously even though the app doesn't require it. Example IE, WhatsApp, etc. (pretty much any app).
This is just like using Nokia Drive for 4 hours and your battery dies.
Constant use of GPS reduces battery life and heats up the phone for no reason.

Whenever *Geofencing* is processing, the phone does it *silently* (the location icon on the top bar is not displayed - it is stated in *location* settings page of the phone)

How do i know its the problem with *Geofencing*?

Here is a little experiment that anybody can try (please don't mock this post if you haven't tried this out):
Turn off location and use your phone normally for a day and you'll notice the battery performance is like pre-update. And phone doesn't heat too.

Comment: The experiment has one little flaw - if I turn of location on my 8.1 phone I am no longer using it the same way I was using the 8.0. Thus I can't compare it that way...

Comment: but did your phone experience heating and battery problems when you used gps continuously in 8.0 , of course it did and this what is actually happening in 8.1 but its a bug with geofencing. the battery would have lasted for same duration (in 8.0) compared to 8.1

Comment: since i posted that post up untill this comment my location was off and im using my phone the same way i used to in 8.0 there is absolutely no heating or a sudden battery drain. if the location was on my battery will lose about 20% in 30min in standby mode.

Answer (score 2):

It has been my experience that Windows Phone "always" has a rough first day or two after a major update or a restore. I've reset various phones of mine on a somewhat regular basis and the following day always seem to be an irregularly bad battery day.

If the trend continues, I would use various battery monitoring tools to track down the situation. It is also good to note that 8.1 now allows you to have more apps running in the background thus giving you more chance to use battery faster. It also gives you the tools to reign it back in too.

Comment: I'm sure there is something wrong related to the app. My battery app used to show I'm loosing less than 5% when a was sleeping. Now just an 8hr sleep costs me about 30%.

Comment: When I first made this comment, 8.1 was out too soon for anyone to make a judgement call on this. Now I'm starting to see reduced battery life consistently too. However, this can be reduced by turning off features and apps. The Battery saver app now allows you to prevent individual apps from running unnecessarily, or people can charge their phones more. If this is a big issue, newer phones will have larger batteries in them to compensate.

Comment: Did a new test yesterday. Full charged and went to sleep. Left the phone without location and with battery saber always on. Woke up with battery at 60%. Looks like when I restart the phone it takes longer to agressively consume battery. About 2 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is related to this:
http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8-1-preview-developers/278439-must-read-lumia-920-owners-running-8-1-whatsapp.html

I have the exact same thing. Phone gets hot and battery drains within 20 hours with or without wifi. Whatsapp is always running even when battery saver is enabled.
It should get an update asap. But I haven't seen a whatsapp update since FB bought them.

Here is a topic on MSDN about battery drain with the wp8.1 preview: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7252d7a5-affe-4e74-9d3c-9a55ccb5ca7b/battery-draining-faster-after-windowsphone-81-update?forum=winphoneosissues